# Crimp and Solder connectors for flexible electronic

Tags: pcb, connector, interconnect, flexible, fpc

I am desperately looking for crimped connectors compatible with flexible PCB and devices such as the one depicted in the following figure :

[image: Measurement Specialities sensor]

This is a pressure sensor based on a piezoelectric polymer. The connectors are crimped-on. It seems very easy to use and very practical for prototyping. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Try phrase "crimping pin for ffc" in google. This gives a selection of links and example of this could be like below: 
[image: Crimping pins]

Be careful. Although the pins are relatively cheap, the price of crimping tools can be massive!

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed "flat cables" is a very good direction. I guess this is exactly the situation where not being a native English speaker nor an educated electrical engineer can lead to dead ends and infinite searches on google :) With you help I identified 1-88997-2 from TE !!